# Primes permutable under any base.

Tags: number-theory

Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $p$ remains prime after any single permutation of its digits in any base different from $p$.

Progress: $p$ must equal $2$ or $2^q-1$ where $q$ is prime (this is just a necessary condition!).

Comment: You probably want to exclude the case of base $p$, because then $p=10_p$, and the permutation $01_p=1$ is not prime.

Comment: That's right! It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with your present proposal $p=2^q-1$, because of the "in any base".

Take $q=5$, which means that $p=\overline{31}^{ten}$ (the upper index means "base ten")  which is a prime number.

I agree that in base 2, $p=\overline{11111}^2$ (the upper index means "base 2")  and you can scramble the digits, you will always get the same prime number.

But if you write this $p$ with base $3$, you get $p=\overline{1011}^3$. If the digits are scrambled in the following way $p'=\overline{1110}^3$, you get the number  thirty  four which is not prime...

This situation will occur every time you have a zero among the digits.

Comment: $2^q-1$ is just a necessary condition that narrows down the answer, that's why I wrote it as "progress". I'm not claiming that all numbers of this form will work. They definitely won't.

Comment: I edited the original post to make this clearer.